# Cenros 6.3 install php-imap cross-repo fails

Tags: php, centos, yum, installation

I am trying to install php-imap support on Centos 6.3

```
yum install php-imap
```

Installation failed due to repos has different php versions:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-14.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3 for package: php-imap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: php-imap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libc-client.x86_64 0:2007e-11.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-imap.x86_64 0:5.3.3-14.el6_3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3 for package: php-imap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-imap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
           Installed: php-common-5.3.18-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common = 5.3.18-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6_2.8.x86_64 (base)
               php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.8
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
```

Trying to installed it with --skip-broken key have this result:

```
Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    libc-client-2007e-11.el6.x86_64 from base
    php-imap-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 from updates
```

My question is: How could I install it from the remi repo directly without checking any versions.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the remi repository in order to install the matching packages from it. I presume you had previously enabled it by some means, in order to get its version of PHP in the first place.

Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and make sure that `enabled=1` is set in the `[remi]` section.

(If it isn't present, make sure you installed `remi-release` RPM first.)